# How do i add event to multiple field of same field

Tags: jquery

Hi How do i add event to multiple field of same form.

In Following code i want to add keypress event to userName also.

```
$("#existingUserForm :input[name='userPassword']").keypress(    
        function(e) {       
        if(e.which == 13) { 
            processLogin();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#existingUserForm :input[name='userPassword'], #existingUserForm :input[name='userName'] ").keypress(    
     function(e) {       
        if(e.which == 13) { 
            processLogin();
        }
 });
```

Read in the documentation about [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `add()` method to add elements to your selection:

```
$('#existingUserForm :input[name=userPassword]')
    .add('#existingUserForm :input[name=userName]')
    .keypress(function() { ...
```

You can also chain multiple selectors inside one `$()` clause by separating them with commas, but the `add()` method is usually better for readability.

You can also use `filter()`:

```
$('#existingUserForm input').filter(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    return name == 'userPassword' || name == 'userName';
}).keypress(function() { ...
```

Easiest method would be to give the elements the same classname, then your selector would simplify to:

```
$('#existingUserForm .checkField').keypress(function() {...
```

...given that your inputs are something like this:

```
<input name="userName" class="checkField" />
<input name="userPassword" class="checkField" />
```